# Referencing values from procedurely generated labels from another userform in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, procedural-generation

I am creating a UI that can Insert, Delete, and Display information from multiple sets of data.  The user clicks the command button to initiate the program, enters some data, and userform1 uses that data to create userform2.  While using userform2, I want the user to be able to update the displayed info on both the userform and the excel sheet based on the information entered into the txtbox generated on userform2.  The issue I am having is that when I try to reference the txtbox and label I generated from UserForm1 for UserForm2 from Userform2, it can't find them.  I used a for loop to name them as well so I thought it should be as simple as either Rag2.caption or UserForm2!Rag2.Caption. UserForm1:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

UserForm1.Show

End Sub

Private Sub CANCELBUTT_Click()

Unload Me

End Sub

Public Sub InsertBUTT_Click()
Dim check As Range
If LINBOX.Value <> "" And NOMBOX.Value <> "" Then
    Set check = Columns("A:A").Find(What:=LINBOX.Value, After:=Range("A1"), _
                LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
    If check Is Nothing Then
        Dim BlankRow As Long
        BlankRow = Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row + 1
        Cells(BlankRow, 1).Value = LINBOX.Value
        Cells(BlankRow, 2).Value = NOMBOX.Value
    End If
Else
    MsgBox "Both LIN and Nomenclature are required to insert a new LIN"
End If

Unload Me
UserForm1.Show

End Sub

Private Sub LINBOX_DropButtonClick()

Dim cl As Range

With ActiveSheet
    For Each cl In Range([A3].CurrentRegion.Columns(1).Address)
        If cl.Value <> "" Then
             With LINBOX
                .AddItem cl.Value
             End With
        End If
    Next cl

End With

End Sub
Private Sub LINBOX_Change()
Dim Rng As Range
Dim cat As Integer
    ' Create a new Combo Box for the overhead categories
    UserForm1.Controls.Add "Forms.ComboBox.1", "CATBOX", True
    UserForm1!CATBOX.Visible = False
        With UserForm1!CATBOX
            .Height = 20
            .Width = 150
            .Left = 100
            .Top = 40
        End With

    If LINBOX.Value <> "" Then

    ' Find the position of the LIN and display the corresponding Nomenclature
        Set Rng = Columns("A:A").Find(What:=LINBOX.Value, After:=Range("A1"), _
                LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
        If Rng Is Nothing Then
    'Do nothing
        Else
            NOMBOX = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rng.Row, Rng.Column + 1).Value

            UserForm1!CATBOX.Visible = True

    ' Fill the combo box with the Category Titles
            With ActiveSheet
                For cat = 1 To 999
                    col = ActiveSheet.Cells(1, cat).Value
                    If col <> "" Then
                        With UserForm1!CATBOX
                            .AddItem col
                        End With
                    End If
                Next cat
            End With
        End If
    End If
End Sub


Private Sub OKBUTT_Click()
Dim Rng As Range, SubRng As Range, subVal As Range, Rngr As Range
Dim Rw As Long, ColSt As Long, ColEnd As Long, i As Long, ScatNo As Long
Dim Rag As Object, Rag2 As Object, Rag3 As Object
 '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
 ' Label the new userform
    If (UserForm1!LINBOX.Value = "") Then
        MsgBox "Your Query wasn't found at this time"
    ElseIf (UserForm1!NOMBOX.Value = "") Then
        MsgBox "Your Query wasn't found at this time"
    ElseIf (UserForm1!CATBOX.Value = "") Then
        MsgBox "Your Query wasn't found at this time"
    ElseIf (UserForm1!LINBOX.Value = "") And (UserForm1!NOMBOX.Value = "") And (UserForm1!CATBOX.Value = "") Then
        MsgBox "Your Query wasn't found at this time"
    Else
        Set LINB = UserForm2.Controls.Add("Forms.Label.1", "LINB", True)
        With LINB
            .Caption = LINBOX.Value
            .Left = 10
            .Width = 50
            .Top = 5
        End With

        Set NOMB = UserForm2.Controls.Add("Forms.Label.1", "NOMB", True)
        With NOMB
            .Caption = NOMBOX.Value
            .Left = 10
            .Width = 200
            .Top = 15
        End With


        Set CATB = UserForm2.Controls.Add("Forms.Label.1", "CATB", True)
        With CATB
            .Caption = UserForm1!CATBOX.Value
            .Left = 400
            .Width = 200
            .Top = 5
        End With
 ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''Merged Columns Start & End''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
        With ActiveSheet

            '' Find the Category in the first row
            Set Rng = .Rows(1).Find(What:=UserForm1!CATBOX.Value, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
            '' If the category is not found, then it won't go through the code
            If Rng Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
            '' Determine the range of the merged columns
            Set Rng = Rng.MergeArea
            Set rngStart = Rng.Cells(1, 1)
            Set rngEnd = Rng.Cells(Rng.Rows.Count, Rng.Columns.Count)
            Rw = Rng.Row + Rng.Rows.Count
            ColSt = Rng.Column
            ColEnd = Rng.Column + Rng.Columns.Count - 1
            Debug.Print Rw, ColSt, ColEnd
            '' Use the merged column range to determine the length of the parser, then print the value
            ''      to the new userform
    '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''SUBCAT TITLE''''''''''''''''''''''''
            Set Rng = .Range(.Cells(Rw, ColSt), .Cells(Rw, ColEnd))
            ScatNo = 0
            '' Establish a row counter
            a = 0
               For Each SubRng In Rng
                    If SubRng.Value <> "" Then
                        ScatNo = ScatNo + 1
                        '' Create a label an give it the subcatagory value
                        Set Rag = UserForm2.Controls.Add("Forms.Label.1", "Scat" & ScatNo)
                        Rag.Caption = SubRng.Value & ":"
                        '' Check if ScatNo is part of the new row or not, anything >7 is, anything <7 is not
                        If a > 0 Then
                        '' Establish when to create a new row (every 7th data set)
                            If (ScatNo Mod 7) = 0 Then
                                Rag.Left = 30
                                Rag.Width = 50
                                Rag.Top = 40 + (a * 20)
                        '' Make the following ScatNos part of the same row
                            Else
                                Rag.Top = 40 + (a * 20)
                                Rag.Left = ((ScatNo + 1) - (a * 7)) * 125 - 85
                                Rag.Width = 50
                                If ((ScatNo + 1) Mod 7) = 0 Then
                                    a = a + 1
                                End If
                            End If
                        '' If ScatNo is less than 7
                        ElseIf a = 0 Then
                            Rag.Left = ScatNo * 90
                            If Rag.Left = 90 Then
                                Rag.Left = 30
                                Rag.Top = 40
                                Rag.Width = 50
                            Else
                                Rag.Left = ScatNo * 125 - 85
                                Rag.Top = 40
                                Rag.Width = 50
                                If ((ScatNo + 1) Mod 7) = 0 Then
                                    a = a + 1
                                End If
                            End If
                        End If
                    End If
               Next
    ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''SUBCAT Values & TXTBOX'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
               Set Rngr = Columns("A:A").Find(What:=LINBOX.Value, After:=Range("A1"), _
                    LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                    SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
               If (Rngr Is Nothing) Then
                   MsgBox "Your Query wasn't found at this time"
               Else
                   Set subVal = .Range(.Cells(Rngr.Row, ColSt), .Cells(Rngr.Row, ColEnd))
                   scat = 0
                   '' Establish a row counter
                   a = 0
                   For Each vale In subVal
                         scat = scat + 1
                         Set Rag2 = UserForm2.Controls.Add("Forms.Label.1", "ScatV" & ScatNo)
                         Set Rag3 = UserForm2.Controls.Add("Forms.TextBox.1", "ScatUp" & ScatNo)
                         Rag2.Caption = vale.Value
                         '' Check if ScatNo is part of the new row or not, anything >7 is anything <7 is not
                         If a > 0 Then
                         '' Establish when to create a new row (every 7th data set)
                             If (scat Mod 7) = 0 Then
                                 Rag2.BackColor = RGB(200, 200, 200)
                                 Rag2.Left = 70
                                 Rag3.Left = 90
                                 Rag2.Width = 50
                                 Rag3.Width = 50
                                 Rag2.Top = 40 + (a * 20)
                                 Rag3.Top = 40 + (a * 20)
                         '' Make the following Scats part of the same row
                             Else
                                 Rag2.BackColor = RGB(200, 200, 200)
                                 Rag2.Top = 40 + (a * 20)
                                 Rag3.Top = 40 + (a * 20)
                                 Rag2.Left = ((scat + 1) - (a * 7)) * 125 - 35
                                 Rag3.Left = ((scat + 1) - (a * 7)) * 125 - 15
                                 Rag2.Width = 50
                                 Rag3.Width = 50
                                 If ((scat + 1) Mod 7) = 0 Then
                                    a = a + 1
                                End If
                             End If
                         '' If Scat is less than 7
                         ElseIf a = 0 Then
                             Rag2.Left = scat * 125 - 25
                             Rag2.BackColor = RGB(200, 200, 200)
                             If Rag2.Left = 100 Then
                                 Rag2.Left = 70
                                 Rag3.Left = 90
                                 Rag2.Top = 40
                                 Rag3.Top = 40
                                 Rag2.Width = 50
                                 Rag3.Width = 50
                             Else
                                 Rag2.Left = scat * 125 - 35
                                 Rag3.Left = scat * 125 - 15
                                 Rag2.Top = 40
                                 Rag3.Top = 40
                                 Rag2.Width = 50
                                 Rag3.Width = 50
                                 If ((scat + 1) Mod 7) = 0 Then
                                    a = a + 1
                                End If
                             End If
                         End If
                Next
     '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
            UserForm2.Show
        End If
End With
End If
End Sub
```

UserForm2:

```
Private Sub CANCELBUTT_Click()

Unload Me

End Sub

Private Sub DELETEBUTT_Click()

Dim RngD As Range
Set RngD = Columns("A:A").Find(What:=UserForm1!LINBOX.Value, After:=Range("A1"), _
                LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
Rows(RngD.Row).EntireRow.Delete
Unload Me

End Sub

Private Sub InsertBUTT_Click()
Dim Rng As Range, SubRng As Range, subVal As Range, Rngr As Range
Dim Rw As Long, ColSt As Long, ColEnd As Long, i As Long, ScatNo As Long
Dim Rag As Object, Rag2 As Object, Rag3 As Object
 ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''Merged Columns Start & End''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
With ActiveSheet

    '' Find the Category in the first row
    Set Rng = .Rows(1).Find(What:=UserForm1!CATBOX.Value, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
        SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
    '' If the category is not found, then it won't go through the code
    If Rng Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    '' Determine the range of the merged columns
    Set Rng = Rng.MergeArea
    Set rngStart = Rng.Cells(1, 1)
    Set rngEnd = Rng.Cells(Rng.Rows.Count, Rng.Columns.Count)
    Rw = Rng.Row + Rng.Rows.Count
    ColSt = Rng.Column
    ColEnd = Rng.Column + Rng.Columns.Count - 1
    Debug.Print Rw, ColSt, ColEnd
    '' Use the merged column range to determine the length of the parser, then print the value
    ''      to the new userform
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''SUBCAT Values & TXTBOX'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
       Set Rngr = Columns("A:A").Find(What:=UserForm1!LINBOX.Value, After:=Range("A1"), _
            LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
            SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
       If (Rngr Is Nothing) Then
           MsgBox "Your Query wasn't found at this time"
       Else
           Set subVal = .Range(.Cells(Rngr.Row, ColSt), .Cells(Rngr.Row, ColEnd))
           scat = 0
           '' Establish a row counter
           a = 0
           For Each vale In subVal
                 scat = scat + 1
                 If UserForm2!Rag3.Value <> "" Then
                    vale.Value = UserForm2!Rag3.Value
                    UserForm2!Rag2.Caption = UserForm2!Rag3.Value
                    UserForm2!Rag3.Value = ""
                 Else
                    UserForm2!Rag2.Caption = vale.Value
                 End If
                 '' Check if ScatNo is part of the new row or not, anything >7 is anything <7 is not
                 If a > 0 Then
                 '' Establish when to create a new row (every 7th data set)
                     If (scat Mod 7) = 0 Then
                         Rag2.BackColor = RGB(200, 200, 200)
                         Rag2.Left = 70
                         Rag3.Left = 90
                         Rag2.Width = 50
                         Rag3.Width = 50
                         Rag2.Top = 40 + (a * 20)
                         Rag3.Top = 40 + (a * 20)
                 '' Make the following Scats part of the same row
                     Else
                         Rag2.BackColor = RGB(200, 200, 200)
                         Rag2.Top = 40 + (a * 20)
                         Rag3.Top = 40 + (a * 20)
                         Rag2.Left = ((scat + 1) - (a * 7)) * 125 - 35
                         Rag3.Left = ((scat + 1) - (a * 7)) * 125 - 15
                         Rag2.Width = 50
                         Rag3.Width = 50
                         If ((scat + 1) Mod 7) = 0 Then
                            a = a + 1
                        End If
                     End If
                 '' If Scat is less than 7
                 ElseIf a = 0 Then
                     Rag2.Left = scat * 125 - 25
                     Rag2.BackColor = RGB(200, 200, 200)
                     If Rag2.Left = 100 Then
                         Rag2.Left = 70
                         Rag3.Left = 90
                         Rag2.Top = 40
                         Rag3.Top = 40
                         Rag2.Width = 50
                         Rag3.Width = 50
                     Else
                         Rag2.Left = scat * 125 - 35
                         Rag3.Left = scat * 125 - 15
                         Rag2.Top = 40
                         Rag3.Top = 40
                         Rag2.Width = 50
                         Rag3.Width = 50
                         If ((scat + 1) Mod 7) = 0 Then
                            a = a + 1
                        End If
                     End If
                 End If
        Next
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
End If
End With
End Sub
```

Clearly I got frustrated with UserForm2 as the code I provided shows me trying to simply write over the already existing labels and txtboxes, but even that's not working.

[Example Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mvwPX.png)

The above link is an example of the data I am attempting to work with (I don't have the rep to embed pictures yet sorry).  All help is appreciated!

Comment: Too much code!  It would be better to post a minimal example which just demonstrates the issue at hand.

Answer (score 0):

What you seem to attempt is to create UserForm1 on the click of a button on the worksheet and UserForm2 on the click of a button on UF1. Then you want UF2 to update UF1 and UF1 to update the worksheet. Your code doesn't do that, in the sense that there isn't an object UF1, nor an object UF2, nor in fact, an object of the worksheet. For example,

```
Dim Ws As Worksheet
Dim Uf1 as UserForm1
Dim Uf2 As UserForm2

Set Ws = ActiveSheet
Set Uf1 = New UserForm1
Set Uf2 = New UserForm2        ' actually to be declared only later in the code
```

Now you might use `Uf1.Show` to display UserForm1 and `Uf2.Hide` to hide it. Bear in mind that `Unload Uf1` removes the form from memory which isn't the case when it is hidden. You can show it again after hiding it or you can unload it and create a new instance of it, depending upon what you want to do.

After creating it with the Set New command, before Show, and after hiding it, but before Unload, you can access all controls of each userform object, like `Uf1.TextBox1.Text` to either read or write. `Ws.Cells(1,1).Value = Uf1.TextBox1.Text` would transfer the content of the text box to the worksheet's cell A1.